# MySQL query working in phpmyadmin but not in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select data from a table in MySQL.
My code in php:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_benutzer, $db_passwort, $db_name);

$results= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE russia = 'привет'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) { 
    echo "Results";
}
else {
    echo "No results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Here I'm getting "No results". But when I run the SELECT-code directly in phpmyadmin i get a result.

What's wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Really? `Here I'm getting 0 results`? You should get either `Results` or `No results`.

Comment: @Error404 it's not the problem.

Comment: $results= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE russia = 'привет'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));    please replace this line with mine and see if any error comes ... without an error i am not able to get the issue

Comment: @Jay What does the following query print in myadmin? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE russia = 'привет'`

Comment: You have a column called Russia?

Comment: @Strawberry: he probably has, as the query works in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have cyrillic characters in your query, so it may be necessary to set mySQL connection encoding. If you are using `utf-8`, insert following line after mysqli_connect:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Or if your script is saved in windows-1251, use the following: `mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'cp1251'");`

For more information about connection character sets and encodings please see [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html)

And why does the query work in phpMyAdmin? Because it probably sets encoding for you in the background.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: If my post answers your question, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

1. You won't get 0 results in any way,you either get results or no results.
   2.try removing the quotes from the table name
2. Check for any Encoding issues with the connection encoding and that the data on the value of column russia is parsed as something else.
   Try executing the following query before executing your main query

   mysqli_query($conn,"SET character_set_results='utf8',character_set_client='utf8',character_set_connection='utf8',character_set_database='utf8',character_set_server='utf8'");

The problems arise if there are Encoding issues in the connection.